# Groovy File uploading and execute

Tags: file-upload, groovy, browser-automation, geb

I want to upload the file in the Query tool page from my application .
I saved all the SQL scripts in my project's folder i need to upload those scripts 1 by 1 and execute it. For my automation test script
And the file uploading is dependent.

please give me some idea's how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information for anyone to really help you. Where are you uploading the file to? What approach have you already tried? Why didn't it work?

Assuming the client and the server are remote, you could upload the file using HTTP. There are many HTTP libraries available in Groovy and Java that you could use. Examples include [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder) that could be used on the client-side and [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) on the server side.

For executing the SQL, the [groovy.sql.Sql](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features) class from the standard Groovy libraries should help.